# Node.js and the Event Loop

Tags: javascript, event-loop, internals

I have some understandings about the event loop in Javascript but there are some concepts I couldn't seem to find answers for on the web.

So, if Node.js has a single stack (because its single-threaded) where code is executed, and there is also an event loop that is in charge of putting tasks into this main stack to be executed, then...

Main Question:

- Where does the event loop run? And how does it communicate with the main thread?

Current assumptions:

- Does the event loop continuously check for tasks to execute? Wouldn't that add significant load onto the main thread?
- if it's not on the main thread, how does it communicate with the main thread? IPC?
- Does the task queue also exist on the main thread? (i know its a data structure but it must have something on top that manages the tasks, no?)

Comment: Nodejs internals are not single threaded. Just like how the browser internals are they also have different threads managing different tasks

Comment: Node.js lets you write code and [run it in other threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html)

Comment: "JavaScript is single-threaded" is an *extreme* oversimplification. It probably does more harm than good when explaining things because it's really wrong. A more precise way of saying is is that *your code* would run in a single thread, not that the entirety of the language is single threaded. Even then, your code can run on multiple threads, too, so that's an oversimplification, too but at least less misleading one.

Comment: @VLAZ, Exactly. It should be JavaScript interpretation is single threaded.

Comment: the developers code is in the main thread, and the event loop needs to communicate with the main thread somehow, so what im asking is how it does that